# Excel checking for intersecting time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to know if it is possible to check if a time period (Column A is start, column B is end) falls between other certain time periods (rows 6 to 8).

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to return the values in column C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=AND($B$1>A6,$A$1<B6)
```

[image]